# Can methane be used as a fuel to launch space vehicles?

Tags: propulsion

Methane is apparently the most easily available hydrocarbon. It is also a flammable, and highly combustible fuel; does burning methane provide sufficient power-weight to be used to launch artificial satellites and their ilk into Earth Orbit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably possible, rockets have been built that used kerosene and even Hydrogen peroxide.
Liquid natural gas stores a lot of energy per volume, but hydrogen is very light and so offers a huge amount of energy per kg. And in trying to accelerate your rocket vertically upward at several 'g' it's kg that matter.

[image: Energy density plot]

Note: data from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density

Comment: Really frustrating that rechargeable batteries are almost at the origin of that diagram...

Comment: @Alexander and diesel is near the top for anything that doesn't need a cryostat !